# How to creat a node for activator attribute in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify give props `activator` in many components such as `v-menu` or `v-dialog`,but there are no more details about how to creat a node to work properly.
The document describe like this

> Designate a custom activator when the activator slot is not used. String can be any valid querySelector and Object can be any valid Node.

But i use querySelector to pick a simple element and it didn't work,any additional property should i add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no additional props. The `activator` prop accept 3 different types.

With Selector:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-btn class="my-btn">Dropdown</v-btn>
  <v-menu activator=".my-btn">
    <v-list>
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</v-app>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kc3ah2dL/)

With Component:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-btn ref="myBtn">Dropdown</v-btn>
  <v-menu :activator="myBtnRef">
    <v-list>
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</v-app>
```

```
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    myBtnRef: null,
    ...
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.myBtnRef = this.$refs.myBtn
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/m54qgcsv/)

With HTMLElement:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-btn>Dropdown</v-btn>
  <v-menu :activator="myBtn">
    <v-list>
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</v-app>
```

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    myBtn: null,
    ...
  }),
  mounted() {
    let button = document.createElement('button')
    button.textContent = 'Dropdown'
    document.body.insertBefore(button, document.body.firstChild)
    this.myBtn = button
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/v0khx9n2/)